# Javascript arrays or objects the difference and how to get the index.

Tags: javascript

From the below code one can discern that the function menu is called with three parameters.
From the menu function how could one get name or diff name depending on which had called menu?

```
var menus = {
    name: menu('Control', [
    {
        label: 'Public Class My Robot',
        trigger: true,
        script: 'public class MyRobot extends SimpleRobot\n{\n[[next]]\n}\n',
        helptext: "Beginning fo your program",
        depend: "package edu.team2648.frcEasyJ;"
    }], false),
    diffname: menu('Control2', [
    {
        label: 'Public Class My Robot',
        trigger: true,
        script: 'public class MyRobot extends SimpleRobot\n{\n[[next]]\n}\n',
        helptext: "Beginning fo your program",
        depend: "package edu.team2648.frcEasyJ;"
    }], false),
};
```

Also what kind of var is menus? (Array, Object,...?)
What is the difference between the following two snippets of code:

```
var test = ["str1","str2","str3","str4"];

var test2 = {id:"str1",id2:"str2",id3:"str3",id4:"str4"};
```

Comment: I suggest you read a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no associative arrays in JavaScript, you need to use objects if you want to assign key:val pairs and simulate the associative array functionality and reference behavior.

`var test = ["str1","str2","str3","str4"];` signifies a numerically-indexed array. We see the square brackets which groups the array, and we only see comma delimited values. If we wanted to access 'str3' we'd use `test[2]`.

`var test2 = {id:"str1",id2:"str2",id3:"str3",id4:"str4"};` is an object. We see the curly braces which groups the object parameters, and we can see the key:val pairs split by the colon. If we want to access 'str3', we'd use `test2.id3`

One thing that might be confusing to beginners is that objects can contain arrays and arrays can contain objects, so the square brackets and curly braces can be mixed in and not be immediately obvious. You can create an array through the Array object like `var arr = new Array()`. To keep things simple, segregate them and call them by their intended behavior: `[]` = array, and `{}` = object.

In your example:

```
var menus = {
    name: menu('Control', [
    {
        label: 'Public Class My Robot',
        ....
```

You can see that `menus` is an object because it's assigned to a curly brace. You can see that `name` is a key and `menu('Control'` is a value, which happens to be a function in this case. It's first parameter is an obvious string, and it's second is an array `[]` which only contains one value, which is an object `{}` which has key:val pairs - `label` being the key, and `'Public Class My Robot'` being the value which is simply a string in this case.

Comment: You conclusion is not 100% correct. Arrays being objects is not related to that fact that arrays (objects) can contain objects (arrays).

Comment: Are you saying their mapping logic isn't the same behind the curtains?

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. To me it sounds like you are saying that objects can contain arrays as values (and vice versa) because arrays are objects. But that is not the case. They can be contained as values because... well.... they are just values.

Comment: Fair enough - I removed the confusing sentence :)

Answer (score 0):

test is an array and test2 is an object.

menus is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` variables is assigned to an `Array` literal. The `test2` variable is assigned to an `Object` literal.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

I have read -- but cannot confirm -- that technically `Array`s and `Object`s are best comparable to hash map constructs in other languages, the difference being that while `Arrays` have only `Number` keys, `Objects` may have any type as the key type (especially `Strings`).
The use of `String` keys in `Array`s (i.e. the use of associative `Array`s) is not suggested in JavaScript.

The `menus` variable is assigned to an `Object` literal.

Please clarify what you mean by this:

> From the menu function how could one get name or diff name depending on which had called menu?

If the `menu` `Function` returns an object of any type, the keys `name` or `diffname` will be mapped to that value: i.e.

```
var nameValue = menus.name ;
var nameDiffValue = menus.diffname ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also what kind of var is menus? (Array, Object,...?) What is the
>   difference between the following two snippets of code:

```
var test = ["str1","str2","str3","str4"]; 
var test2 = {id:"str1",id2:"str2",id3:"str3",id4:"str4"};
```

`test` is an Array, which is an Object.

`test2` is an Object. In Javascripts [objects can be represented as associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html): a property id on the `test2` object can be accessed as `test2.id` and also as `test2["id"]`

So, `test` and `test2` are both objects and arrays

Comment: Just on a quick side note to say, "objects can be represented as associative arrays", imo does not make a whole lot of sense. Hashes (hash maps) can be represented as `Objects` in JavaScript. An associative `Array` already is specific kind of `Object`

Comment: If you change that, I'll +1 your answer.